# Matching a string that starts with a specific character

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get some Regex to match and string that begins with ~ and ends with a space or the end of the line.

It's part of a Wiki Converter I'm cobbling together... I need to wrap anything that starts in ~ upto the next space (or EOL) in  tags.

Example strings are:

```
"~Test"          // matches Test
"~----"          // matches ----
"~Test Bob"      // matches Test
"~Test, Bob"     // matches Test,
"Some ~Test Bob" // matches Test
"Some ~Test"     // matches Test
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?<=~)[^\s]+
```

Read as "look behind for a tilde, then match anything after that except for whitespace."

Comment: Thanks, added ()'s to get exclude the tilde from the match.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=~)\S+
```

Same as the other answer, but better match for non-whitespace.
Or, simpler,

```
~(\S+)
```

If you are using group anyway